# when i am using xamarin MVVM. so how to handle Device Back(Hardware back button) in view model

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, cross-platform

I am creating one app in xamarin cross platform with MVVM, I want to handle device back navigation so how can i handle it? please help me.

Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's quite simple actually just add a command in your VM and call that command from your View when you need to handle this event!

In your View

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
   var vm = (ViewModel)BindingContext;
   if(vm.MyBackPressCommand.CanExecute())  // You can add parameters if any
     {
         MyBackPressCommand.Execute(); // You can add parameters if any
     }
}
```

Also, define this in your ViewModel

```
public ICommand MyBackPressCommand { get; set; }
```

And also this needs to be initialized(constructor) like below:

```
MyBackPressCommand= new Xamarin.Forms.Command(()=>{});
```

You can use inheritance to make this globally available for all derived versions of your View/ViewModel

Comment: if i dont want any parameter then what should be parameter.?

Comment: Nothing, Just leave it empty or null whatever suits you!